Is it possible to override the default Allocator in C++ with out manualy specifying it in each constructor
C++ standard library containers such as std::vector accept an optional template parameter that lets you specify an alternate allocator. The examples I can find show this happening at each object creation via the syntax:
std::vector<T,custom::custom_allocator<T> >
Is there a way to globally set custom::custom_allocator<T> such that I don't need to include it in the template arguments every time? Preference would be for solutions that do not require wrapping the stl in custom code, or using processor text substitution.

Create a type-alias, like template<typename T> using vector_custom_allocator = std::vector<T, custom::custom_allocator<T>>;?

What's wrong with being explicit? You will only type the code once, but it will be read many more times later (by your future you or other maintainers). The fact that the custom allocator is there shows you intend this vector to be allocated in a specific way (and thus makes the code self-documenting)

@PepijnKramer, I commonly see this need when people try to incorporate (global) logging of allocations, by providing a slight variant of std::allocator. And then they don't want to change all the code for this.

@alfC I can see the need, and the alias approach from Some programmer dude is a nice way to both document and to globally be able to replace with std::allocator later again.

Logging allocation in std containers is only good for educational purposes. Debugging std library is the platform developers' task. I can not see any benefits in a logging allocator in serious code.

@PepijnKramer: it's not "you only type the code once" though. You have to go edit every single std::string and std::vector and std::map and such in the entire codebase.

@PepijnKramer Developer ergonomics, trying to make sure that when my cognitive load is being spent on RealWork(tm), I don't shoot myself in the foot by forgetting the template param.

@TaylorE fair enough :)

@Red.Wave, this is not to debug the STL but to log the memory usage by the program. I am not saying it is the best way, I am saying that's what people commonly reach for. Nowadays, some people say that you should use PMR, for which adding logging is "easy" and precisely allows to change the allocator globally (and dynamically). I am not sure is a good alternative either.

I'd use a type alias, and modify all the affected code so it uses that type alias (in a header, included where needed) instead of std::vector.   That may be intrusive initially but, once done,  it is simple to change the type alias as needed  e.g. template<typename T> using custom_vector = std::vector<T, your::allocator<T>>; when you need the custom allocator, and template<typename T> using custom_vector = std::vector<T>;  to switch back to using the standard allocator.  Code that doesn't ever need the custom allocator can continue using std::vector as usual.

You can globally override ::operator new and ::operator delete with the same effect. It will however apply to the whole executable. It can't be restricted to individual translation units or libraries.

@alfC  I thought about pmr too. But I can not identify the main problem here yet.

@Red.Wave I am doing some experiments around making the common STL containers more "game engine" friendly, work in a similar vein as the EASTL. the main issue i run into with the EASTL is that you have to remember to use it, its not a set-and-forget replacement.  I want to make the ergonomics of using the modified containers easier.

@TaylorE if you are on the EA dev team, then you need more investigation in particular std implementations. Otherwise, you should know that despite similarlities in some aspects, EASTL is very different from std. But at least, this puts pmr out of immediate horizon, because it means polymorphic allocator.

@TaylorE, if you are looking for containers that work with modern allocators and fancy pointers, see this (of mine): https://github.com/correaa/boost-multi#polymorphic-memory-resources (and other sections)

@Red.Wave im not on the EA team, this is work for a personal/hobby engine project that provides reasons for me to delve into less explored C++ corners  like this.

@TaylorE I don't find EA's approach on this matter appealing. std is way more generic and flexible than EASTL. Data alignment is exactly the responsibility of allocator. EASTL claims to be considering GC, but by droping construct and destroy members from allocators, it eventually closes the path toward GC. More importantly GC support was partially added to C++11 and deprecated in C++23, because std proved to not need it. C++ RAII is more than enough for dealing with GC.

@Red.Wave getting off topic here, but im less interested in GC and more interested in things like allocating a huge chunk of memory at program init, and then giving chunks of it to my containers as needed to avoid the cost of dynamic memory allocation at runtime.

@TaylorE that's a perfect fit. Define a Mayer singleton in your allocator, with a std::unique_ptr member to actual storage.

I generally find namespaces a good way of separating own and third party code. They can be used in various ways to organize self documentig code. For this case I would regroup all my required containers in a namespace:
namespace my_containers{
    template <
        typename T,
        typename alloc = custom_allocator<T>
    > using vector = std::vector<T,alloc>;

    template <
        typename C,
        typename trait = std::char_traits<C>,
        typename alloc = custom_allocator<C>
    > using basic_string = std::basic_string<C, trait, alloc>;

    using string = basic_string<char>;

    /*Define aliases for other template types*/
};

Now you can switch with a compiler defined macro:
#ifdef USE_STL
    namespace containers = std;
#else 
    namespace containers = my_containers;
#endif

And a local namespace injection in function scope is not bad:
void foo(){
   using namespace containers;
   vector<int> my_vec;
   string my_str;
   /*Blah blah*/
};

By introducing an extra boolean argument, I could ditch the preprocessor like this:
namespace containers{

    constexpr bool use_stl = false;

    template <typename T>
    using allocator = std::conditional_t <
        use_stl,
        std::allocator<T>,
        custom_allocator<T>
    >; // allocator<T,choice>

    template <
        typename T,
        typename alloc = allocator<T>
    > using vector = std::vector<T,alloc>;

   /*Do the same for string and rest*/
};

By changing the value of use_stl you can choose the desired implementation at compile-time.

If you use std::pmr::vector, then you can pass in whatever allocator in the constructors, and not have to make any further changes to code that references but does not create new vectors.  (pmr stands for polymorphic)
Alternatively, use template<class T> using myvector = std::vector<T, custom::custom_allocator<T>>;
